# Is the Cyclic Decomposition the coarsest decomposition among those with terms of cyclic subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Fix a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ and a linear operator $T$ on $V$, we know that we have the Cyclic Decomposition (actually, the Invariant Factor Decomposition) $$V = F[T] \alpha_1 \oplus \dots \oplus F[T] \alpha_m$$ (where $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_m$ are non-zero vectors in $V$) which satisfy $p_{\alpha_m} \mid p_{\alpha_{m-1}} \mid\dots \mid p_{\alpha_1},$ where $p_{\alpha_i}$ denotes the annihilator of $\alpha_i$.

Now suppose we have another decomposition $$V = W_1 \oplus \dots \oplus W_n$$ where the $W_i$s are cyclic, which is NOT necessarily the Invariant Factor Decomposition. Is it true that we necessarily have $m \leq n$?

We know that, intuitively, the Invariant Factor Decomposition is the "coarsest" decomposition, the question naturally generates from my effort of trying to make the mentioned intuition precise.

Comment: No, since the number of summands in a cyclic decomposition is not unique. For example, $F[x]/(x(x-1)) \cong F[x]/(x) \times F[x]/(x-1)$ as $F$-vector spaces and also as $F[x]$-modules. So a cyclic module can be a direct sum of two nonzero cyclic modules. There are special types of cyclic decimpositions with uniqueness properties: look up “elementary divisor decomposition” and “invariant factor decomposition”.

Comment: As an example, let $T = (\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix})$ act on $F^2$. Its characteristic polynomial is $x^2-x = x(x-1)$ to relate this to my previous comment. This has eigenvectors $w = \binom{1}{0}$ and $w’ = \binom{0}{1}$, so $F^2$ has the cyclic decomposition $Fw \oplus Fw’$ with $m=2$ in your notation. Also $F^2$ has basis $\{u,T(u)\}$ where $u = \binom{1}{1}$, so $F^2$ has a cyclic decomposition with $n=1$ in your notation.

Comment: Sorry for confuse, I thought when it comes to vector spaces, people assume that they're talking about the invariant factor decomposition when they say "the" Cyclic Decomposition.

Comment: I think it would be better to add that information to your question. I would not assume a cyclic decomposition is the invariant factor decomposition unless that is explicitly mentioned. It is quite useful that some calculations can be made with an arbitrary cyclic decomposition. In algebraic number theory, finitely generated modules over a PID come up all the time and it is *very* convenient there that many calculations with finitely generated torsion modules over a PID can be made with an arbitrary cyclic decomposition of the module; the invariant factor decomposition is hardly ever required.

Comment: Already added. Thanks a lot for the comment on the background information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simplifies notation to do this over a general PID $R$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_m\in R$ be non-zero (in your setting they correspond to the $W_i$ via $W_i\cong F[T]/\langle a_i\rangle$).  We will describe how to obtain the elements $p_1,\dots, p_n\in R$ such that $p_1\mid\dots\mid p_n$, $p_1\notin R^\times$ and $$R/\langle p_1\rangle\oplus\dots\oplus R/\langle p_n\rangle\cong R/\langle a_1\rangle\oplus \dots\oplus R/\langle a_m\rangle$$ From this procedure it will be then clear that $n\leq m$.
Let $q_1,\dots,q_l$ be prime elements in $R$ such that there are integers $r_{ij}\geq0, i=1,\dots,m, j=1,\dots,l$ such that \begin{align*}
a_1 &= q_1^{r_{11}}\cdots q_l^{r_{1l}}\\
a_2 &= q_1^{r_{21}}\cdots q_l^{r_{2l}}\\
&\dots\\
a_m&=q_1^{r_{m1}}\cdots q_l^{r_{ml}}
\end{align*}
Now construct the sequence $b_1,b_2,\dots$ as follows: for each $j=1,\dots,l$ select $i$ so that $r_{ij}$ is minimal, take the corresponding term $q_j^{r_{ij}}$, cross it out the list above and let $b_1$ be the product of these $q_j^{r_{ij}}$ for $j=1,\dots,l$ (the $i$ depends on $j$). Then proceed similarly for $b_2,\dots$ by only considering those powers of the $q_j$ which haven't been crossed out yet. Clearly after constructing $b_1,\dots,b_k$ in each column (in the set of equations above) exactly $k$ elements have been crossed out. Thus this has to stop after $m$ steps and we get by construction a sequence of elements $b_1,\dots,b_m$ such that $b_1\mid \dots\mid b_m$ and $$R/\langle a_1\rangle\oplus \dots\oplus R/\langle a_m\rangle\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\bigoplus_{j=1}^lR/\langle q_j^{r_{ij}}\rangle\cong R/\langle b_1\rangle\oplus \dots\oplus R/\langle b_m\rangle$$

Now some of the factors $R/\langle b_i\rangle$ might be zero because some of the powers $r_{ij}$ might have been $0$, $b_1=\dots b_k=1$ for some $k\geq0$. Then the $p_i$ will be those $b_i$ that are non-units, i.e. $p_i := b_{i+k}$ for $i=1,\dots,m-k=:n$.